# What kind of JTAG connector is this?

Tags: connector, jtag, socket

I have two circuit boards that are almost identical. One has a JTAG socket, and one does not. I want to add a socket to the one that doesn't have one, but I don't know which part to get.

This is the socket in question:
[image: JTAG Connector]

This is what the board looks like without one:
[image: Missing JTAG Connector]

Comment: What chip does the jtag go to?

Comment: "Micromatch" I think

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is pretty close:

http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/8-215079-0/A99470TR-ND/1955697[image]

Comment: Just got in touch with the manufacturer. They confirmed, this is the one.

Comment: @DirkGroeneveld Great :)